# Add The $ sign before the fine

Tags: c#

I am writing this code in Visual Studio  but it did not show me the extract output as `$2354`

```
Console.WriteLine("Fine: {0:C}",myticket.Fine);
```

It shows me

```
Fine: ? 2345
```

Comment: What culture are you in? It should show your default culture's currency, but it's possible that the console may not be able to display it without changing the code page.

Comment: What's the result of `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);` and `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);`?

Comment: Another thing to consider is the content of `myticker.Fine`. Is that an amount in the local currency or is it in US dollars?

Comment: yes it is in decimal

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet to get the result in dollar currency

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Fine : {myticket.Fine.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))}");
```